# Генерация древовидных структур и их фильтрация

Tags: дерево, javascript, d3.js

Здраво!

Для работы с древовидными структурами d3 предоставляет объект [Hierarchy](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout). На базе этого объекта сделано несколько шаблонных генераторов. Все они, как и сам объект, делают примерно одно и то же: принимают данные, анализируют их и на основе анализа выдают массив элементов A, упорядоченных так, что для каждого элемента A[n] и его родителя A[p] p<n.

Таким образом пробежавшись по массиву можно построить линейную структуру, что чаще всего и происходит:

```
var hr = d3.layout.hierarchy();
var root = get_data();

d3.select('#content').select('ul').selectAll('li')
    .data(hr(root), function (d) {return d.id})
    .enter()
        .append('li')
        .html(function (d) {return d.name})
        .style('margin-left', function (d) {return d.depth * 35 + 'px'});
```

Результатом будет структура типа:

```
<ul>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;">root</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 35px;">child 1</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 70px;">child 1.1</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 35px;">child 2</li>
</ul>
```

Визуально она подходит, однако работать с таким выводом не очень приятно. Можно ли все-таки сделать ее иерархической? Примерно так:

```
<ul>
    <li style="margin-left: 0px;">root
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px;">child 1
                <ul>
                    <li style="margin-left: 70px;">child 1.1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 35px;">child 2</li>
</ul>
```

И еще вопрос. Как можно фильтровать древовидные структуры? Предположим, есть фильтр, который пропускает child 1.1, но не пропускает child 1. Однако так как child 1 — родитель child 1.1, его тоже нужно нарисовать, иначе структура нарушится.

Comment: По последнему вопросу непонятно, если у вас узел графа удален, то как же вы предполагаете сохранить связи?

Comment: @eicto, в этом и проблема. Скорее всего, прийдется писать какой-то хитрый фильтр, не использующий стандартного selection.filter. Вообще, оба вопроса решаются в лоб рекурсивными штуками. Но я надеюсь, что есть готовый инструмент для решения задачи. В конце концов не похоже, чтоб вопрос был таким уникальным.

Comment: @Zelta, это не проблема, если нет узла в направленном графе, то нет и его потомков.

Comment: @eicto, вот что я пытаюсь добиться: к примеру, дерево файлов.

    root
      |_file1

Если запрос на фильтрацию — `file`, то `file1` пройдет валидацию, а вот `root` — нет. Но тогда и `file1` не отобразится. В общем, прийдется писать свой фильтр похоже. Первый вопрос все еще открыт.

Comment: Погодите, а покажите сэмпл вашего массива тогда? Он не похож на этот: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout ?

Comment: Именно, похож. Но вывод я хочу не в svg, а в html. На svg все просто: рисуем элементы, зная x и y, потом соединяем. В html же хочется вложенности.

Comment: Вот что там происходит: на вход получаем

    {
    id: "0", name: "root",
    children: [
        {id: "1", name: "C1",
            children: [
                {id: "2", name: "C1.1"}
            ]}
        ]
    }

А на выходе:

    [
        {id: "0", name: "root", parent: undefined, children: Array[1]},
        {id: "1", name: "C1",  parent: [Object], children: Array[1]},
        {id: "1", name: "C1.1",  parent: [Object]}
    ]

То есть обычный массив, элементы которого ссылаются друг на друга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нарисовал демо к вот этому ответу (исправил в нем пару моментов), https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028839/815386

http://jsfiddle.net/cyxsu2oz/1/